# Fragment transaction custom animation - Android

Tags: android

I am trying to do: 
`ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);`

But I am getting an exception with Unknown animation name: objectAnimator - see details below:

```
04-08 10:45:41.637: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1222): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 10:45:41.637: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1222): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: objectAnimator
04-08 10:45:41.637: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml(AnimationUtils.java:124)
04-08 10:45:41.637: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml(AnimationUtils.java:91)
04-08 10:45:41.637: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimationUtils.java:72)
```

Why is there an error? I am not sure how to solve it. Please Help. Thanks.

FYI: My min sdk is 7, but I am build for sdk 11 with compatibility library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to target 3.0 (API level 11) to use the new object animator. If you are building for lower versions you must use the older anim transitions (android.R.anim).

However, I think that fragment animations in the compat library are broken as stated by Dianne Hackborn in [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/5ef5ba1be9f40c56/a846578d91a032c0?hide_quotes=no) post.

Comment: My app is supporting sdk 7 to 11. The build target is 11 and I am loading the app on Motorola Xoom.

Comment: **QUESTION**: Is there any other way to have some custom animation during the fragment transition?

Comment: @mgv please I would like to know if it is still broken as well

Answer (score 4):

I forked the support library to add support for using [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com) animators in custom fragment transitions. Note that they only work with CustomTransition and not via theme settings. Object animators *must* be used as View animations will no longer work.  [android_frameworks_support](http://www.github.com/kedzie/support_v4_nineoldandroids)

Comment: Hello, Mark. Could you provide compiled jar file?

Comment: Give me an email and yes.  Otherwise use maven to build the project.  Pom is in v4 subdirectory.  just do maven install

Comment: I added the compiled jar to the github repository

Comment: @mark.kedzierski Thanks a  lot! Please how to we use this jar?

Answer (score 0):

When your app is over level 11 API.

Change this on imports

- import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

with this

- import android.app.Fragment;

Ensure your app not contains support.v4 import on your imports, otherwise, will have troubles with compilation.