# How to use Fragments and objectAnimator in older Android versions?

Tags: android, android-fragments, objectanimator

I tried to use fragments and objectAnimator to make flip animation like [here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html), and everything was ok on Android 4.1, but when I'm trying to add `android-support-v13. jar`, use FragmentActivity and launch it on older version, animation between fragments crashes the app with this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: objectAnimator
```

Please, can you say me how to use objectAnimator or how to create flip animation using common Android animation?

UPD: I also tried to use http://nineoldandroids.com/, but I can't understand how it can be used for activity transition animation.

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596860/fragment-transaction-custom-animation-android....they are saying android.R.animator are broken while using with animatorsetCustomAnimation.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#declaring-xml

> Starting with Android 3.1, you should save the XML files for property
>   animations in the res/animator/ directory (instead of res/anim/).